# Mobile site view is missing blue OP highlight in comments

Tags: bug, comments, mobile-web, design

Lately, I've noticed that on questions in the mobile view, comments written by the original poster do not have the light blue highlight around their name. The highlight appears, however, as soon as I use the “add / show more comments” function (on all of OP's comments on the post, not just newly visible ones).

Example [answer which shows the problem](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/36008/pcb-part-naming-for-leds/36019#36019), before and after clicking:

> [image: Before: Comment by OP, no highlight.]
>
> [image: After: One added comment, already visible comment has highlight.]

I was using Chrome for Android on my phone but this problem occurs on all browsers I've tested on, when using the mobile view (the above screenshots are from desktop Chrome).